# A simple AIU trigger doesn't work

Tags: firebird

Is this trigger written correctly? I want it to prevent amount or pricenet to be zero. These columns are defined as domains with decimal data type.

```
CREATE OR ALTER trigger invpos_biu0 for invpos
active before insert or update position 0
AS
begin
  IF('INVPOS.AMOUNT' = '0.00' or 'INVPOS.PRICENET' = '0.00')
  THEN exception zero_value;
end
```

Im using IBExpert if its relevant. When I insert data with 0 values it doesnt react.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your trigger is comparing the string (`CHAR`) `'INVPOS.AMOUNT'` to `'0.00'` and `'INVPOS.PRICENET'` to `'0.00'`. The result of these comparisons are always false and therefor do not raise the exception.

You clearly want to compare the (new) value of the column. When you use triggers you can retrieve the new values with the `NEW` context variable (which has all the columns of the table) and the old values with the `OLD` context variable.

I think you want the condition:

```
IF(NEW.AMOUNT = '0.00' or NEW.PRICENET = '0.00')
```

Or if these values are `DOUBLE PRECISION`, `NUMERIC` or `DECIMAL`:

```
IF(NEW.AMOUNT = 0.00 or NEW.PRICENET = 0.00)
```

That said: instead of a trigger you should use a `CHECK` contraint on the `AMOUNT` and `PRICENET` columns. That is a lot clearer and visible than a trigger.

In Firebird you can use column and table level check constraint, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE INVPOS (
    ...,
    CONSTRAINT CHK_INVPOS_NONZERO CHECK (AMOUNT <> 0 OR PRICENET <> 0)
)
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE INVPOS (
    ...,
    AMOUNT DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL CHECK (AMOUNT <> 0),
    PRICENET DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL CHECK (PRICENET <> 0),
    ...
)
```

Note you can also name constraints, which is easier for error handling. See the Firebird 2.5 Language Reference, [`CREATE TABLE`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-ddl-tbl) for details.